# What is the difference between maven update and maven build?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

With m2e-plugin we can right click on a project and then click on *Maven update* or we can click on *Run As -> Maven build*. What is the difference between them? What is the background operation that is performed when each option is chosen?

Because as far as I can see.. the information provided in that status bar says that it is *"Building the workpace"*. What does it mean by that?
What exactly is updating the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run maven update - your local maven repository gets updated with the latest jars from central repository. This is important for SNAPSHOT versions of artifacts. SNAPSHOT version of artifacts in the local repository maybe out of date with what's currently available in your central repository.
*build happens in eclipse because the build automatically option is selected. if it's not it won't happen.

When build - complies, runs test and builds you current projects artifacts. maven build usually includes a maven update phase unless run with the offline option (-o).

Comment: so does that eclipse clean build after maven upodate and maven build are same

Comment: clean build deletes all the code that was complied and re-runs the full build process. If you just run build, it will only re-build any artifacts that have changed from the previous build.

With maven update you can force it to go look for newer version of snapshot artifacts. A regular build may or may not do that depending on when the maven had tried to get the latest versions of the dependent artifacts.
They are in general similar but have stubble difference and nuances